# An issue with SLComposeViewController sharing text appear blank ios9

Tags: ios, slcomposeviewcontroller

i am using SLComposeViewController for sharing on facebook and twitter.
when i perform action then open dialog box but there are no any text is appear in dialog box.

Comment: Maybe fb forbids to prefill it now.  Read the Facebook Policy at https://developers.facebook.com/policy 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Facebook update their policy it always blank.

Possible solution: create your own alert view ([push me](https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGAlertView)), integrate FacebookSDK ([push me](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)) and implement sharing ([push me](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/samples/ShareIt/ShareIt/SIMainViewController.m)).

The easiest way to integrate sdk is through CocoaPods.